# Blender 3.1 in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't start

Tags: error, opengl

When I try to run Blender it gives me this error:

```
Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.
```

I've read many answers related to this error but the solutions were for different situations than mine. On my computer I have a Radeon R9 290 Tri-x but I'm using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 20.04 so the graphic card I see is 'VMware SVGA II Adapter'. I can run blender with this command 'LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./blender' but it's very slow. So i'm asking, how can i run blender normally? Thanks

Comment: I think you haven't found a suitable answer yet, because the answer may not be universally applicable. Too many individual parameters play a role here and there are probably a multitude of possibilities. Anyway, from experience I can only advise against even trying to run Blender in a VM unless you want to use it headless (command line). The main problem is simply that no suitable graphics card drivers are usable in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: @quellenform Thanks for the comment, I'm gonna probably install Ubuntu in dual boot